# Change Bottom Navigation's Icon Position

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

with the button action I change my selected fragment from another fragment. However, when I change the fragment, the bottom navigations icon does not change. The selected icon still shows the first fragment's icon.

```
ContactFragment contactFragment = new ContactFragment();
                                     FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                                     manager.beginTransaction()
                                             .replace(R.id.fragment_container,contactFragment,contactFragment.getTag())
                                             .commit();
```

[image]

The shown image is a contacts fragment but the icon stays in the settings section. How can I change the icon? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the icon onclick, and then on the switch case you need to set only the one you need to change, so only when selected the icon change.

```
    Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
menu.findItem(R.id.action_favorites).setIcon(favDrawable);

switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.setting:
                     item.setIcon(favDrawableSelected);
                case R.id.contact:
                case R.id.dupicated:
            }
```

Comment: You can just modify the switch to your uses.